# Regex for replacement

Tags: c#, regex

If I have an `string` like this:

```
MyObject[0]
```

I want to use a `RegEx` to insert a `()` before the `[

So I would end up with:

```
MyObject()[0]
```

I used `String.Replace` but that could end up causing problems if there's already a `()`.

```
.Replace("[", "()[")
```

Example:

```
MyObject()[0].Items[0]
```

Would end up

```
MyObject()()[0].Items()[0]
```

Wanting to use a regex to do this to avoid duplication.

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"[A-Za-z]\[", "()[");
```

The problem here is it replaces the preceding character:

```
MyObjec()[0]
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look for word characters followed by [ and only replace in that case (vs. if the word characters are followed by (.

For example:

```
 Regex.Replace(
  input, 
  //find expression
  @"(\w+)(\[)", 
  //replacement expression
  @"$1()$2")
```

Answer (score 1):

use a grouping around the `A-Z` block in your replace to bring back your `t`:

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"([A-Za-z])\[", "$1()[");
```

Test from LinqPad:

```
Regex.Replace("MyObject[0]", @"([A-Za-z])\[", "$1()[")
```

Output:

```
MyObject()[0]
```

Comment: This will produce MyObject()()[] if the input string is MyObject()

Comment: Ah yes.  Misread it.  It fails the other case though. MyObject[].Items[]

Comment: it's a bit unclear how he wants that to work. this regex puts `()`s before any `[]`, which i *think* is what he wants.